# Prestashop 1.7. : Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: parameters, themes, prestashop

I'm in DEV mode on PS and now i get this error. Its from my theme Amera, and laberstaticblocks are the ones that you move around the homepage.

what kind of error is this one?
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
in labertaticblocks.php line 354
at labertaticblocks->hookdisplayHome(array('cookie' => object(Cookie), 'cart' => object(Cart), 'altern' => 2))
in Hook.php line 990

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHBQs.png)

Comment: Which PHP and PS versions are you running?

Answer (score 0):

You are using PHP 7.2 or above, and this module is trying to use `count()` on something that is not an array. You should contact the theme/module author to fix this issue for you.